# Error XamlParseException Adding a reference from my WPF Custom Control Library to my WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2013

I have this issue with my ResourceDictionary. I'm using the MVVM Pattern with Visual Studio 2013 C# WPF application 4.5.

In my solution there is 3 Assembly.

- Login (Contains Model/View/ViewModel/Repository for Login : WPF Application)
- MainProject (after the login the Main Screen Show up : WPF Application)
- WindowTemplates (Contains all my Themes of Window styling : WPF Custom Control Library)

The project begins with the Login Project, It shows the Login screen + do validation etc .. when click on Login and everything is good users exists in DB I do a new MainWindowViewModel.cs. In My MainWindowViewModel I set the default properties and do a MainWindowView.show() it gives me an Xaml Error.
I don't understand why I've looked threw searches for ResourceDictionary and I believe I do the same thing yet it gives me an error.

MainWindowViewModel.cs Code :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    #region Private Fields
    private MainWindowView _MainWindowView;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public MainWindowView MainWindowView
    {
        get { return this._MainWindowView; }
        set
        {
            if (this._MainWindowView == value)
                return;

            this._MainWindowView = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.MainWindowView = new MainWindowView();

        this.MainWindowView.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.MainWindowView.Show();
    }
}
```

My MainWindowView Xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="MainProject.View.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTemplateWindow}"
    Title="MainWindowView" Height="200" Width="200">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/WindowTemplates;component/DefaultWindowTemplate.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

In My WindowTemplates Assembly I have the DefaultWindowTemplate.xaml just styling my window without a border that's all
code :

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultTemplateWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border x:Name="WindowBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColorBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="10"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In my MainProject I've added a reference to the WindowTemplates Assembly, **there is no compile error**. It even applies my styling when the program isn't running so I do know for a fact that my styling is working because I can see it. Only at run time it gives me an error on the line :

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/WindowTemplates;component/DefaultWindowTemplate.xaml" />
```

Yes, the DefaultWindowTemplate.xaml is on the root of my assembly

**EDIT :**
**ERROR GIVEN**
XamlParseException occured
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occured in PresentationFramwork.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.

Thanks

Comment: Exception?  I don't see any exception.  Your question contains no exception.  Therefore there isn't any problem.  Or, you should catch it, call ToString on it, then paste the result in an [edit].

Comment: Alright I just fixed it, it seems like I needed to add the WindowTemplates Assembly in my Login Assembly since my Login Assembly is the "Main" (my starup Project) Assembly ... I thought it would go into my MainProject Assembly and load my WindowTemplates Assembly but doesn't seem that way ...

Comment: K.  And you didn't paste the exception details.  FYI, calling ToString on the exception, or using the exception helper dialog (there's a "copy details to the clipboard" link near the bottom) and pasting it into your question is important.  You'll get all details and the stack trace for the exception and all inner exceptions.  That's often enough detail to answer any question.  You can add an answer below with your solution and select it as correct; that's what we do in this situation normally.  Congrats on getting it solved!